# bash exec command makes while loop too many times?

Tags: bash, unix

i have 2 text files 1.txt and 2.txt.

1.txt consists of names and ids separated by a tab, like so:

```
Doe,John    123456
Smith,Jack  234678
Green,George987987
West,Mae    444555
```

2.txt consists of ids and grades also separated by a tab, like so:

```
234678  B
123456  A+
444555  B+
987987  C+
```

i want to take the id from each line in 1.txt, search 2.txt for a match, then output the name and grade associated with that number into a new file.

expected output:

```
Doe,John A+
Smith,Jack B
Green,GeorgeC+
West,Mae B+
```

so what ive done is:

```
>namegrades.txt

exec < $1 #read from 1.txt
while read line
do       #store the name and the id for the current line
    number=$(echo "$line" | cut -d$'\t' -f 2); 
    name=$(echo "$line" | cut -d$'\t' -f 1);
    echo $name # used to test
    exec < $2   #take input from 2.txt
    while read line
    do #store the grade and check the current line in file for a matching id
        grade=$(echo "$line" | cut -d$'\t' -f 2);
        check=$(echo "$line" | grep -c $number)
        echo $check    
        if [ $check == 1 ]; then  #if there is a match echo to new file
    #echo "$name    $grade" >> namegrades.txt
            echo hello   #used to test
        fi
    done < $2
done < $1
```

when i run the code the output i get is:

```
Doe,John
1
hello
0
0
0
123456
1
hello
0
0
0
123456
1
hello
0
0
0
```

repeated to infinity.I am new to unix and dont know how to fix this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every time you run `exec < $1`, it starts over at the very top of the file. Why are you doing that?

Comment: BTW, it's **vastly** more efficient to run `while IFS=$'\t' read -r name number; do` rather than read the whole line but then use `cut` to split it.

Comment: Why are you using both `exec <$1` and also redirecting the input of the `while` loop?

Comment: There's no TAB after `Green,George` in `1.txt`.

Comment: BTW, as another aside, `[ $check == 1 ]` is buggy on multiple fronts; `[ "$check" = 1 ]` will be more portable to baseline-POSIX shells, and less buggy (if your variable is empty, or globbable, or contains content that would look like `test` arguments after being string-split)

Comment: `grep -c $number` should be `grep -c "$number"` in case `$number` is empty or has whitespace.

Comment: i was not aware that done < redirected the input of the while loop, removing exec fixes my problem. thanks

Comment: Instead of using nested loops that reread `2.txt` every time, you should read `2.txt` into an associative array once.

Comment: What did you think `done < filename` did? If you didn't know that's what it did, why did you write it in the first place?

Comment: i am taking a beginners course in unix and this is my first time coding with it. we were expected to do this only being taught a few basic features. much of this i was able to put together by trying to look it up. my unix knowledge is very lacking.

Comment: `join -t ' ' -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 -a 2 -o '1.1 2.2' <(sort -k2,2n 1.txt) <(sort -k1,1n 2.txt)` where the -t parameter is a tab

Comment: `paste <(sort -k2,2n 1.txt) <(sort -k1,1n 2.txt) | cut -f1,4`  (this assumes that all the IDs appear in both files)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.
Read each file in a while loop via IFS. Compare ID1 of `1.txt` with id2 of `2.txt` and if equal append to third file.

This does picks up on some of the discussion and puts it together as a solution.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name id1
do
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r id2 grade
  do
    if [ "$id1" == "$id2" ]; then
      printf '%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$grade"
    fi
  done < /tmp/2.txt
done < /tmp/1.txt |tee -a /tmp/3.txt
```

Result

```
Doe,John     A+
Smith,Jack   B
Green,George C+
West,Mae     B+
```

Comment: The inside of the loop is the **worst** place to put the `tee`: You're starting new copies of `tee` over and over and over, paying startup costs each time. Instead, `| tee /tmp/3.txt` should go *after* the last `done`, to use just one instance for the entire stream. Also, consider `printf '%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$grade"` rather than `echo`; that'll be significantly better-behaved with unusual values (try a name of `*` for an example).

Comment: great suggestions, +1,  Didn't think of that. Answer updated. Although this answer is baseline based on OP's current requirements and does not cover different exceptions.